# Use the header of each data container in the rows of their respective values

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

[Google Sheets Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VRad7zC6RCwLi6xyxv8fyQ0k5Xfl0nFVh26xbwizA50/edit?usp=sharing):

[image]

Using `SORT` to reverse the sequence of cells to do a bottom-up `VLOOKUP`, to some extent it finds the correct values as you can see in the image above.

The default formula I use for each row is this (Image → Column H):

```
=IF(E3="","",VLOOKUP("",ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SORT({SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&row()),"<>''")),{INDIRECT("B2:B"&row()),INDIRECT("A2:A"&row())}},1,FALSE),"Select Col2, Col3"),"","§")),2,FALSE))
```

But for some reason I couldn't understand, this search stops working and the result is always empty.

And when trying to use the same formula with `ARRAYFORMULA` so you don't have to put a separate formula for each row, it always delivers the first value, even if I add the full range in each `ROW` (Image → Column I):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E3:E="","",VLOOKUP("",ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SORT({SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&row(E3:E)),"<>''")),{INDIRECT("B2:B"&row(E3:E)),INDIRECT("A2:A"&row(E3:E))}},1,FALSE),"Select Col2, Col3"),"","")),2,FALSE)))
```

What is the correct method to arrive at the expected result that is in Column F (painted in green)?

Note: The most reliable use would be using `ARRAYFORMULA` because I don't know how to say the maximum number of lines it can reach, so it would be more advantageous to have an option that can adjust itself according to new lines appearing automatically.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in row 2:

```
=INDEX(IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A2:A), "\d+:\d+")),,VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), 
 IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A2:A), "\d+:\d+")), {ROW(A2:A), A2:A}), 2, 1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Add the INDEX() function to the formula

For starters, you may use the following modified formula as the basis of your formula:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("E"&ROW()) = "","",INDEX(SORT({SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&row()),"<>''")),{INDIRECT("B2:B"&row()),INDIRECT("A2:A"&row())}},3,FALSE),1,3))
```

You may "drag down" the formula to the whole column.

### Output

The expected output of this function can be seen in `column G` in the image below.

[image]

### References

- [INDEX()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)

Comment: Please feel free to ask if you have any questions. With regards to further improvements to the formula, I am still trying to figure out how to apply the `arrayformula()` function to the formula.